# sequence in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be sequences in the closed unit ball in a Hilbert space. Prove that if $\langle x_n,y_n \rangle→1$ then $\lVert x_n−y_n \rVert→0$.

(From the *Fundamentos de análise funcional* by Botelho Pellegrino.)

Can I say from the assumption that it is an orthogonal basis within the Hilbert space? Also, how does the other assumption about the closed unit ball help me?

Comment: Hint: $2\langle x_n y_n\rangle = \|x_n\|^2 + \|y_n\|^2 - \|x_n - y_n\|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine you always have $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\langle x_n,y_n\rangle\leqslant\|x_n\|\|y_n\|\leqslant1$ and since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n,y_n\rangle=1$, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|\|y_n\|=1$. It follows from this and from the fact that you always have $\|x_n\|,\|y_n\|\leqslant1$ that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|y_n\|=1.$$And then\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n-y_n\|^2&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|^2+\|y_n\|^2-2\langle x_n,y_n\rangle\\&=1+1-2\\&=0.\end{align}

Comment: $||x_n||\leqslant 1$ and $||y_n||\leqslant 1$ it is stated that they belong to the closed unit ball, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.